# Sending email message to gmail account asp.net

Tags: email, gmail, send

I have a problem to send an email message to gmail account.
   Situation is the following, I'm using IIS6 Default SMTP mail server to send emails.
   It sends emails to all mail clients, except gmail.
   Here is the code:

```
SmtpClient serv = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add("my gmail account address");
            msg.From = new MailAddress("some email address");
            msg.Body = "body";
            msg.Subject = "subject";
            msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
            serv.Host = "localhost";
            serv.Send(msg);
```

Can you tell me what can be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it send's mail to all clients what do you mean? The SMTP server would be forwarding mail to other SMTP servers, for example mail.gmail.com on port 25. Your mail client then connects to mail.gmail.com to collect the mail.

I would check to see if your ISP has blocked port 25 outbound. It is a common anti-spam measure. Some mail providers will use the alternate port 26. Make sure proxies and firewalls permit access to gmail.

Failing that, see if the server running the SMTP can resolve gmail using DNS.

I'm pretty sure there should be a dropped mail folder on the SMTP server. Check there for failed messages - you might get more information.

Comment: ok, I have tried to send mail to mail.ru using the same code  and there is no problem, but when I try to send email message to my gmail account it doesn't. It creates a file in mailroot\Queue directory and later it removes the file from there and create a file in mailroot\Badmail folder. Please, can you tell me what can it be? Am I missing some configuration for gmail? Thanks.

Comment: Check the bad mail result, open it up, and it might tell you why the gmail could not be sent.